# how to make checkbox and the title in the same line

Tags: html, css

In google chrome, pressing F12 and turn on toggle device toolbar.
You will see checkbox and title are not in the same line in the second checkbox.
I want to keep the bootstrap stylesheet, how to make the checkbox and title in the same line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
     <input name="agreement"  type="checkbox" >
     <label for="agreement">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
   <br >
     <input name="promotion" type="checkbox">
   <label for="promotion">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would work.Try This:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<style>
  .promotion{
    display: inline;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
</style>
<body>
     <input name="agreement"  type="checkbox" >
     <label for="agreement">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
   <br>
     <input name="promotion" type="checkbox">
   <label class="promotion" for="promotion">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label><br>
</body>

</html>
```

You can read about word-break here:- 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "div" tag to wrap them up

```
  <div class="chkbox1">
    <input name="agreement"  type="checkbox" >
     <label for="agreement">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
   </div>

   <div class="chkbox1">
     <input name="promotion" type="checkbox">
   <label for="promotion">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</label></div>
```

with "div" tag you can even give it actual css and you don't need a "br" tag for spacing

Answer (score 0):

Change the html markup as below and apply below css:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <label>
    <input name="agreement" type="checkbox">
    <span>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input name="promotion" type="checkbox">
    <span>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
  </label><br>
</body>

</html>
```